# Using parenthesis for calculation in C

Tags: c++, opencv, parentheses

I have an assignment of dithering using OpenCV. I understand this method and coded it in C++, but I found what I can't understand about parenthesis.

When I execute this code:

```cpp
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<highgui.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/cvconfig.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat img = imread("lena.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat bgr[3];
    Mat dithering[3];
    int x = img.rows;
    int y = img.cols;
    Mat merger;
    Mat temp(x, y, CV_64FC1, Scalar(0));
    double e;

    split(img, bgr);

    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
        bgr[l].convertTo(temp, CV_64FC1);
        for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < y - 1; j++) {
                if (temp.at<double>(i, j) > 127)
                    e = temp.at<double>(i, j) - 255;
                else
                    e = temp.at<double>(i, j);

                temp.at<double>(i, j + 1) = temp.at<double>(i, j + 1) + e * (7 / 16);
                temp.at<double>(i + 1, j - 1) = temp.at<double>(i + 1, j - 1) + e * (3 / 16);
                temp.at<double>(i + 1, j) = temp.at<double>(i + 1, j) + e * (5 / 16);
                temp.at<double>(i + 1, j + 1) = temp.at<double>(i + 1, j + 1) + e * (1 / 16);
            }
        }
        dithering[l] = Mat(x, y, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                if (temp.at<double>(i, j) > 127)
                    dithering[l].at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
                else
                    dithering[l].at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    merge(dithering,3, merger);

    imwrite("dithered.jpg", merger);
    namedWindow("original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("dithered", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow("original", img);
    imshow("dithered", merger);

    waitKey(0);
}
```

I have these results

[image]

These are very bad results.

But when I delete parenthesis in the calculation:

```cpp
temp.at<double>(i, j + 1) = temp.at<double>(i, j + 1) + e * 7 / 16;
temp.at<double>(i + 1, j - 1) = temp.at<double>(i + 1, j - 1) + e * 3 / 16;
temp.at<double>(i + 1, j) = temp.at<double>(i + 1, j) + e * 5 / 16;
temp.at<double>(i + 1, j + 1) = temp.at<double>(i + 1, j + 1) + e * 1 / 16;
```

I got the right results:

[image]

I couldn't find the difference between them, but they bring different results.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: You are aware that integer 7/16 is 0, aren't you?

Comment: In `e * 7 / 16` the variable  `e` is of type `double`, so `7` and `16` are both promoted from `int`  to `double` before multiplying/dividing them.   However, in `e * (7 / 16)` the parentheses force `7/16` to be calculated first.  Both `7` and `16` are of type `int`, so dividing them produces an `int` - with value zero.   That is then promoted to `double` to  multiply by `e`.

Answer (score 3):

In this expression

```
e * (7 / 16)
```

the sub-expression in the parentheses is evaluated using the integer arithmetic. That is the result of `7 / 16` is equal to 0. So the full expression is also equal to 0.

Without the parentheses the expression

```
e * 7 / 16
```

is evaluated like

```
( e * 7 ) / 16
```

and here there is used the arithmetic with float numbers (the variable `e` is declared as having the type `double`) because objects of the type `int` are implicitly converted to the type `double` due to the usual arithmetic conversions to determine the common type of the expression.